# Splitting multiple overlapping date range interval in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using postgresql version 10.9 and I am trying to split overlapping intervals from 2 different tables that record events.

For each interval of the main table, I need to detect the person movement (arrival or departure) that overlaps the main interval, and split it for each prod_line by the event. If the person movement is arrival, I need to take the highest value of a 5 minutes interval consecutive arrivals. If the person movement is departure, I need to take the lowest value of a 5 minutes interval of consecutive departures.

I only found samples of merging overlapping intervals for date ranges within the same table. 
I tried to write a function that loops through the main data set and for each interval to loop through the attendance intervals and return overlapping intervals. 
I failed to make the attendance intervals take into account the highest arrival_time within a 5 minute interval and the lowest value within a 5 minute interval for departure time and also further compare it to the main current interval to properly split it as expected.

My 2 tables have the following structure

```
main (prod_line text, item_code text, start_time timestamp without time zone, end_time timestamp without time zone); 
attendance(person_id text, prod_line text, arrival_time timestamp without time zone, departure_time timestamp without time zone);
```

having the following sample data for *Main:*

```
    "RS-5";"110067805";"2019-06-11 06:30:41";"2019-06-11 15:00:05"
```

and for *Attendance*

```
    11770;"RS-5";"2019-06-11 06:30:09";"2019-06-11 11:00:12"
    675;"RS-5";"2019-06-11 06:30:14";"2019-06-11 10:00:01"
    11504;"RS-5";"2019-06-11 06:30:17";"2019-06-11 10:00:07"
    101;"RS-5";"2019-06-11 06:30:23";"2019-06-11 11:00:10"
    627;"RS-5";"2019-06-11 06:30:25";"2019-06-11 11:00:20"
    11765;"RS-5";"2019-06-11 06:34:29";"2019-06-11 11:00:01"
    675;"RS-5";"2019-06-11 11:30:09";"2019-06-11 15:00:25"
    627;"RS-5";"2019-06-11 11:30:16";"2019-06-11 15:00:24"
    11504;"RS-5";"2019-06-11 11:30:19";"2019-06-11 15:00:18"
    11770;"RS-5";"2019-06-11 11:30:22";"2019-06-11 15:00:15"
    11765;"RS-5";"2019-06-11 11:30:25";"2019-06-11 15:00:12"
    101;"RS-5";"2019-06-11 11:30:27";"2019-06-11 15:00:30"
    353;"RS-5";"2019-06-11 15:01:39";"2019-06-11 15:10:35"
    11712;"RS-5";"2019-06-11 15:01:42";"2019-06-11 15:10:34"
    817;"RS-5";"2019-06-11 15:01:44";"2019-06-11 15:10:32"
    1337;"RS-5";"2019-06-11 15:01:46";"2019-06-11 15:10:30"
    1363;"RS-5";"2019-06-11 15:01:48";"2019-06-11 15:10:28"
    1510;"RS-5";"2019-06-11 15:01:50";"2019-06-11 15:10:24"
```

[Rextester Fiddle](https://rextester.com/MROQ2823)

Basically, I would like to get a result of the intervals looking like this:

```
    result (prod_line text, item_code text, start_time timestamp without time zone, end_time timestamp without time zone);
```

with the values

```
    "RS-5";"110067805";"2019-06-11 06:34:29";"2019-06-11 10:00:01"
    "RS-5";"110067805";"2019-06-11 10:00:07";"2019-06-11 11:00:01"
    "RS-5";"110067805";"2019-06-11 11:00:01";"2019-06-11 11:30:27"
    "RS-5";"110067805";"2019-06-11 11:30:27";"2019-06-11 15:00:05"
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "highest (lowest) value of a 5 minutes interval consecutive arrivals (departures)".  Also an example of how that is derived leading to a couple of the desired outputs indicated.

Comment: Hi, thanks for trying to help me out. Let me try to explain a more clear. For example in Main, for line RS-5, I have the start_date as 06:30:41. I need to check what happened in the attendance table in a 5 minutes interval around this time, and get the highest value between the 2 tables, in this case, I need it to be  06:34:29.

Comment: For this same line, the end_time is 15:00:05. I need to check what happened between 6:34:29 and 15:00:05. In this case, there is a person leaving at 10:00:01. So this needs to generate an interval as 6:34:29 up to 10:00:01. And then I need to check the next event (either arrival or departure) between 10:00:01 and 15:00:05. There are multiple departures around 11:00, and I need the lowest of those: 11:00:01. So for this line, for June 11th, I hope to get the 3 intervals 06:34:29 -> 10:00:01, 10:00:01 -> 11:00:01, 11:30:27 -> 15:00:05.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else needs a solution for this, I figured something out (maybe not the best but it works)

The solution is [available here](https://rextester.com/MROQ2823)